# iPhone app background downloads

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm making an app that receives constant updates (potentially hundreds of times a day) and, to make for a better user experience, it would be nice to have these downloaded in the background.

Looking at Apple's<sup>[[1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)]</sup> documentation I need to set the background mode to "Background fetch". Exploring deeper you can read about the `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler`<sup>[[2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)]</sup> function which states that:

> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the specified completion handler block... If your app takes a long time to call the completion handler, it may be given fewer future opportunities to fetch data in the future.

The problem is our downloads ***will*** take longer than 30 seconds to download, and as such would rather not face the wrath of Apple sending updates fewer and farther between, thus exacerbating the issue!

So, am I able to do this somehow?

Also, I have created a crude experiment whereby I create a `NSTimer:scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` to run every minute which logs to the console. This successfully works both on the iPhone in simulation (has been running for 30 mins plus) and also when I place it on a phone (a week plus)... why would this be!?

Comment: If your downloads really take longer than 30 seconds, potentially hundreds of times a day, you're probably going to face the wrath of users without unlimited data or memory first. You could also use performSelectorInBackground in your app to do essentially the same thing (it would seem from your description) without dealing with background fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

You can bypass Apple's `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler` function and set your own timer. To do this make sure you do the following:

1. Have selected `Background fetch` under Your app settings > "Capabilities" > "Background Modes".
2. In `AppDelegate.m`, within `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, add the following code:

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
       // Nothing
   }];
   ```
3. You can now add a `NSTimer` in your `AppDelegate` and it will continue to run whilst in the background. E.g.,

   ```
   _timerBg = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1800
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(bgFunction)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It may be hard to do because of the Apple 30s obligation. They decided so to eventually prevent big download to happen not to drain battery and data plan.

You must be sure you really need to download that much data (as it takes this long) in background, plus hundred times a day!

I mean, when your app goes foreground after a (long) background period, it may not be updated and it's normal case. So you need to do the update when the app goes foreground; only one update is needed. Otherwise, you should step back and rethink the update process.

Comment: We'll be providing delta updates so each download will be relatively tiny (a couple of k, and take way under 30 seconds). However, if the user does not have a consistent connection then those updates will slowly grow and will take longer than 30 seconds to download/process. It is these in which we do not want to be punished for, since it would mean the update process would be called less often, resulting in exactly these larger downloads.

Comment: Ok, so this is different now. What you need is to set some mechanism to call your backgroundWork method, like a NSTimer. `self.backgroundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:100.0 target:self selector:@selector(backgroundWork) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];[self.backgroundTimer fire];` In this example you repeat the backgroundWork every 100s. Call this on event `didEnterBackground` and it will work. Though, an app is to be terminated by the OS a few minutes after entering background (i'd said 4"). That's why the _Background fetch_ should be checked.

Comment: So, if we were planning to update every 5 minutes then the `NSTimer` would never actually fire a second time (assuming the app is "terminated" after 4 minutes)? Also, I read in Apple's docs that you should [stop all timers when entering the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html)?

Comment: No, it should not terminate as you specify in your plist that you need background tasks. I read about stoping all timers: it's not an obligation. You may want to take a look at this : [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). Also, i don't know the type of data you receive via updates, but maybe the Newsstand Kit framework can do the trick for you (referenced in that link).

Comment: Have just tried setting a `NSTimer` in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` to run every 20 seconds. It succeeds the first time but then no longer registers. Seems as though the 30 second app suspension kicks in!

Comment: If your NSTimer is a local variable, i suggest you save it as a class variable and check again. But that's the point i start guessing, as for me, the same kind of work is required for audio stuff (i checked "Audio and AirPlay", not "Background fetch"), but so far this works the same.

Comment: Ok, I have found that adding the following in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function seems to make everything magically work: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ /* Nothing */ }];`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: => [...] your app could call this method to ensure that had enough time to transfer an important file to a remote server or at least attempt to make the transfer and note any errors. **You should not use this method simply to keep your app running after it moves to the background.**